# Share image through Whatsapp or Facebook Inbox

Tags: ios, facebook, share, whatsapp

I was using an Android and i saw that is possible select a photo from camera roll and share via whatsapp.

Is it possible with iOS? Can i implement this feature to my iOS app? Else can i select a photo in my app and share via Facebook Inbox?

Thanks

Comment: As far as I knw NO, just like for opening any link you have only safari as option , you do not get to choose from other browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatsapp have an integration now

https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/iphone/23559013

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/use-camera-and-photo-library-in-iphone/) tiny tutorial out on how to pick an image from Camera Roll or take a picture from Camera. Then you can implement methods to share the pic via Facebook, Email, Twitter etc.

Comment: Thanks Pheel, but I'm looking for a restrict way. That i share a photo with a specific contact, like SMS but using whatsapp or facebook inbox